# Azure Access Control - Failed to remove user

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I created user role for Azure Storage. After one minute I tried to remove it but the system return error:

Failed to remove user
Failed to remove xxx.xxx as Owner for xxxstorage.

I didn't do anything else with this user just add it and then try to delete it.

Comment: Check the role is Inherited or not, Inherited role assignments cannot be removed.

Comment: Scope is: This resource

Comment: Try to use powershell to remove it, `Remove-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId <object id> -RoleDefinitionName <role name> -Scope <scope such as subscription id>`

Answer (score 1):

By default there is a Delete lock in storage. You need to go to Locks and delete "Delete" lock. Portal does not give you any hint what is wrong, but if you use Powershell it throw error that -Scope is locked.